# How to transpose data in Excel while using the 1st column as unique identifier?

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I need help transposing some 3rd-party Excel output that comes in this format below:

| Employee | Question | Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Q1 | Yes |
| Bob | Q2 | No |
| Bob | Q3 | 100 |
| Jane | Q1 | No |
| Jane | Q2 | No |
| Jane | Q3 | 50 |
| Tom | Q1 | No |
| Tom | Q2 | Yes |
| Tom | Q3 | 0 |

Background:
This is survey data containing up to 10 questions and each employee MUST answer each question. So if data was collected from 10 employees for a survey of 3 questions, then the output file will contain (10x3) 30 rows of data

I need to rearrange this data for the "business side" and I realized that the desired output is beyond the scope of simply using TRANSPOSE() in Excel

Here is the final result that I've been asked to design

| Employee | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Yes | No | 100 |
| Jane | No | No | 50 |
| Tom | No | Yes | 0 |

Basically, I need 1-row per employee with each question horizontally lined up and their responses.

Is this even possible? If so, any help would be greatly appreciated!

cheers

Comment: Index() with match(), and similar has been done on here.

Comment: Glad you edited your typo - threw some of us for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

It is a simple `Pivot` with no aggregation, and can actually be done entirely from the UI.

*I did change your table 1 as Jane seems to have two different answers to Q2 - I suspect the numerical answer is really for Q3*

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//read the data
//change the table name in next line to actual table name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table34"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Employee", type text}, {"Question", type text}, {"Response", type any}}),

//Pivot with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Question]), "Question", "Response")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: YES!  That's exactly what i was looking for
Thanks for suggesting to use Power Query, definitely need to get more familiar with that function in Excel

Answer (score 0):

So this works, with an extra column in column D:

```
=A2&B2
```

So based on your data:

[image]

So, formula in cell B13:

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH($A13&B$12,$D$2:$D$10,0))
```

The issue with your data is that Jane has two of Q2... I had to correct that.

For your list of names, you could copy and use remove duplicates or use unique().